# Can new properties be added to an object that has been defined?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Suppose a javascript object has already been defined.

```
var parent =
{
    child1: {property1: "xx", property2: "xx", property3: "yy"},
    child2: {property1: "xx", property2: "xx", property3: "yy"}
};
```

Later on, the programmer wants to add new properties such as `child3` and `child4` to the `parent` object dynamically. Can this be done or does a new object need to be created from the merging of the existing `parent` object and the new properties?

Comment: It can be done directly.`parent.chid3 = {}`

Comment: Hey! That's the answer!

Comment: @Rajesh, you can put it as an answer. I will choose it as the answer. Your credit.

Comment: May I ask why the negative vote on the question? Please explain so that I can improve in future.

Comment: Perhaps because adding a property to an object is a rudimentary operation in JavaScript which any tutorial would cover on the first page?

Comment: Thats fine buddy. Also i believe this is a very basic question and a little googling would have solved it, so negative vote.

Comment: What is obvious to others is not obvious to me. I humbly admit so.

Comment: @ Rajesh, no problem. Never mind the negative votes. I am happy so long as I get the right answer:)

Comment: @user1824987 Good luck with your JS learning process. Unfortunately, SO is not really oriented towards Q&A about language basics. It's meant to be a repository of interesting programming problems, not a sort of forum for beginners. As a result, questions like this one are likely to be downvoted or voted to close, which is not a pleasant experience. Everyone went through the stage of being a JS beginner at some point, but most of them read tutorials, books, blog posts, and documentation, which is how things like this became "obvious" to them. That's probably a good approach for you to take too.

Comment: @ torazaburo, thanks for your encouragement. The good thing about the internet is that nobody can see the idiot face behind the idiot questions. So, once a person gets used to it, who cares? Besides, I don't really think basic questions are completely useless. If a downvoted question attract comments and answers besides downvotes, then it still must have some value to the programming community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clearify:

```
parent.chidl3 = {}
```

Works in this case. Cred to Rajesh.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comment from Rajesh. Here is the answer. Credit goes to Rajesh.

```
var parent =
{
    child1: {property1: "xx", property2: "xx", property3: "yy"},
    child2: {property1: "xx", property2: "xx", property3: "yy"}
};

parent.child3 = {property1: "xx", property2: "xx", property3: "yy"};
parent.child4 = {property1: "xx", property2: "xx", property3: "yy"};
```

Comment: What is wrong with the answer? Why the negative vote?